# DDL script generation in Query Analyzer

Tags: sql-server

Is there any way that i can generate the DDL scripts fro all the objects (tables,procdures etc) in SQLquery analyzer at a time? 
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

### For SQL Server

- You can use `sp_helptext` to generate the scripts for stored procedures.
- You can use [this](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic422424-338-1.aspx) or [this](http://www.builderau.com.au/program/sqlserver/soa/Script-Table-definitions-using-TSQL/0,339028455,339293405,00.htm) to script out tables.

You can create a cursor for the following queries -

```
SELECT * FROM sys.tables;
SELECT * FROM sys.procedures;
```

You can then run through the cursor and emit the scripts for the tables and procedures using `PRINT` statement, and voila, you have to scripts in your message window.